# Correct understanding of module axioms

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, definition

I am trying to understand the module axioms.

Below should be the standard module axioms taken from Artin's 'Algebra':

Let R be a ring. An R-module V is an abelian group with law of composition written +, together with a scalar multiplication $R \times V \longrightarrow V$, written $r, v \mapsto rv$, which satisfies

- $1v = v$,
- $(rs)v = r(sv)$,
- $(r+s)v = rv + sv$,
- $r(v+v') = rv + rv'$.

According to the axioms, though it sounds wrong, this construction is legal, right?: Let $V := \mathbb{R}$. Then V is a $\mathbb{Q}$-module because it satisfies all above axioms with the scalar multiplication by $q \in \mathbb{Q}$. If this is wrong, what is wrong?

Comment: Yes, it's perfectly good. Why should you doubt it?

Comment: If $R$ is a field, it is called a *vector space*.

Comment: @egreg In the same book there is an exercise Chp 12 1.4 (a) "Let V be an abelian group. Prove that if V has a structure of $\mathbb{Q}$-module with its law of composition as addition, then this structure is uniquely determined.". Here I somehow assume that the unique structure is to mean $\mathbb{Q}$. However, I defined above V to be $\mathbb{R}$ which is a $\mathbb{Q}$-module. Should a group with $\mathbb{Q}$-module structure generally be isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$? Or Do I rather misunderstand the meaning of "structure"?

Comment: @taro This exercise asks you to prove that there is only one possible scalar multiplication $\Bbb Q\times V \to V$ satisfying the axioms, but this can hold for different abelian groups $V$; for example $\Bbb Q^n$ is a $\Bbb Q$-module for all $n$.

Comment: @taro Of course not: $\mathbb{Q}^2$ is a vector space over $\mathbb{Q}$ and is certainly not isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$.